# Error 403 with Ckan 2.6.2 - Datapush

Tags: postgresql, ckan

I have, in order to process some big data, to set up ckan on a local machine. I've set up the whole system following this guide : http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html

I wanted to display a preview of a locally loaded file, so the user can actually see it before downloading it. And it doesn't work, because it only works for online files. For instance, it DOES work with [this online file](http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv) but NOT with my own file I upload.

So, I've been interested about Datastore and Datapusher. I've followed every part of the guide, and it appears on my ckan. However, I have an error. Specifically this one :

> Upload error: An Error occurred while sending the job: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://127.0.0.1:8800/job

Here's my most important parts about my production.ini file (copying the whole would be very long) :

```
ckan.site_url = http://localhost

ckan.plugins = datastore datapusher stats text_view image_view
recline_view recline_graph_view recline_map_view webpage_view

ckan.datapusher.formats = csv xls xlsx tsv application/csv
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

ckan.datapusher.url = http://127.0.0.1:8800/
```

I truly have no idea about what my problem could be, I tried to change the datapusher.url to 0.0.0.0 as the guide suggested, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If the data to be added to CKAN is in a file on your computer, select “Upload a file” option. CKAN will give you a file browser to select it. You should use link to a file option just for publicly available resources.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed datapusher also? Its a separate process running on port 8800. CKAN uses datastore to be able to have a grid view of tabular data. Data needs to be pushed through datapusher to be used by datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set up the Datapusher.It's not activated by default.

Pull the datapusher code, install the dependencies and run it using:
`python datapusher/main.py deployment/settings.py`

The instructions to configure the settings are on the repository.

Here's the datapusher manual: http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/
Here's the repository: https://github.com/ckan/datapusher

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same error message.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697258/xlsx-file-not-showing-in-the-data-explorer-ckan) solved my issue though.

short: insert/check the following in your virtualhost in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/datapusher.conf

```
<Directory /etc/ckan>
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```