# Xlsx file not showing in the data explorer ckan

Tags: xlsx, ckan

I am running a ckan instance on ubuntu 16.04.3. I installed the latest ckan from source. I uploaded a few xlsx files successfully but when I try to view them in the data explorer it keeps on loading and shows no views or gives this error on the interface:

```
"This resource view is not available at the moment. Click here for more information.

Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Please read the dataproxy API format documentation: https://github.com/okfn/dataproxy)"
```

When I try to upload the file to the datastore I get the following error on the interface:

```
Upload error: An Error occurred while sending the job: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://127.0.0.1:8800/job
```

In the datapusher.error.log I see:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 4296:tid 139631223842560] [client 127.0.0.1:36692] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /etc/ckan/datapusher.wsgi
```

Also I cant see any specific error in my terminal when I serve my development.ini file. How can I view the xlsx files in my data explorer successfully?

Comment: Do you have any HTTP authentication set up on the server... via nginx/Apache? In case it helps your debugging, what is happening is that CKAN accesses datapusher as an external service and then the datapusher is accessing CKAN, as an external service (although it looks like it isn't getting that far).

Also see the Office Document previewer: https://github.com/jqnatividad/ckanext-officedocs

In case previewing is your main concern

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the folder containin datapusher.wsgi acessible to apache in your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/datapusher.conf?

```
<Directory /etc/ckan>
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```